# How to delete orphaned Google Calendars + Events?

Tags: google-calendar-api

My app performs a one-way sync to Google Calendar. As in, if you create an event in my app it will be added to Google Calendar, but you can't update that event from Google Calendar.

I store all the Google Calendar IDs and Event IDs that their API gives me back so that I can update the calendars + events later.

However, I'm concerned about orphaned records. If, for example, someone deletes an event in my app but either the API request fails to delete the corresponding event from Google Calendar or my app has a bug in it, then that record will become orphaned -- it will exist on Google Calendar but I will have no reference to it.

So what's the best way to delete orphaned records?

Here are my ideas:

1. [Download a list](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) of every single event ID in Google Calendar, fetch all the event IDs out of my database, do a set subtraction to determine which ones are orphaned, and then delete those [one-by-one](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/delete).
2. [Delete the entire calendar](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/delete) if I notice a mishap, and then [re-sync](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) all the events.

The problem with (1) is that it might get quite memory intensive once I've accumulated a lot of events. The problem with (2) is that a full re-sync can take awhile and those events will be missing from Google Calendar while the sync is happening. Plus, I might have a race-condition if users are creating new events during the sync.

What's the best approach? Are there any other solutions?

Comment: Has this actually happened? I think if you make sure that [Events.delete](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/delete) is executed properly, where it returns HTTP 204, you should be ok.

Comment: @noogui Hasn't happened yet, no, but I just finished coding up this feature. I'd be surprised if they weren't a couple bugs left in it. What if Google's servers go down for a bit? My app can't stop working just because Google won't send me a 204, and I need to delete/amend the record in my own database regardless of what Google says.